# How to reopen the ios project when remove the remove the reference?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I am new to IOS.

I developer the ios project by using **Xcode 5**, and I delete the project by using `"remove reference"`.

I want to open the same project again , I have double click the `project.xcworkspace`.
But it doesn't work , it show **No File** in xocde5.

How to re-open the same project in xcode 5??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still also have a `project.xcodeproj` file?

Comment: Yes , I have 'project.xcodeproj'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accidentally removed a file (or Xcode project) from the list in the Project Navigator pane, just locate the file in the Finder and drag&drop where it was before in the Project Navigator pane.

The same can be accomplished with command "Add Files to ..." which is the "+" button in the lower left in the Navigator pane, or menu command "File" -> "Add Files to ..."

Comment: If I use menu command "File" -> "Add Files to ... . Should I add all file and folder?

Comment: @Martin If you removed an Xcode project, e.g. `my_project.xcodeproj`, just add this "file" (actually it's a bundle, but it appears _as if_ it's just one file).

Answer (score 0):

Providing you had no extra settings / projects within your workspace, you *could* just get rid of it and continue working with just the `xcodeproj` file.

Otherwise, open up the `xcworkspace`, and drag your `xcodeproj` back into it from the Finder, into the file navigator on the left hand side.